# What is c# equivalent of Java's getAndSet

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to write c# code that does similar to this java code:

```java
public class Syncer {
    private AtomicBoolean syncInProgress = AtomicBoolean(false);

    // Data is synced periodically and on user request
    // and these two calls may overlap
    public void SyncData() {
        if (flag.getAndSet(true)) {
            return ;
        }

        // Sync data...
        // It is enough that one thread is syncing data

        flag.getAndSet(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote code that is not thread safe

Comment: Not familiar with atomic operations in C#, but `Interlocked.Exchange`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think your question is about AtomicBoolean or getAndSet!? I think it's about the fact that you want your method to execute only once when multiple concurrent calls are done to the method while it's still processing. In that case my answer with Montior.Enter should do the trick for you, and is thread safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I concur with chris, [`Interlocked.Exchange(ref Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a(v=vs.110).aspx), used with only 0, 1 is the replacement.

The description of the method:

> Sets a 32-bit signed integer to a specified value and returns the original value, as an atomic operation.

The description of [`AtomicBoolean.getAndSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html):

> Atomically sets to the given value and returns the previous value.

Sadly there is no `Interlocked.Exchange()` with `bool` (and note that the `Interlocked.Exchange<T>()` is for reference types!)

The code given in the question:

```
public class Syncer
{
    private int flag = 0;

    // Data is synced periodically and on user request
    // and these two calls may overlap
    public void SyncData()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref flag, 1) == 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Sync data...
        // It is enough that one thread is syncing data

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref flag, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just note that if your `// Sync data...` area is working on updating a reference type, you might want to look at using `Interlocked.Exchange<T>` on that data in a compare-and-swap loop...  This method as is might not be as threadsafe as it appears at first glance.

Answer (score 3):

[`Interlocked.Exchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you're looking for.  Unfortunately, as mentioned, you can't use it with `bool`, which is a shame.  One alternative is to use the `int` overload as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838087/2779530).

The "magic number"-ness of this solution has always personally bothered me a little bit.  But there's a way you can make a reference type that otherwise acts like a `bool`:

```
public sealed class RefBool
{
    public static implicit operator bool( RefBool value )
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public static implicit operator RefBool( bool value )
    {
        return value ? RefBool.True : RefBool.False;
    }

    public static bool operator true( RefBool value )
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public static bool operator false( RefBool value )
    {
        return value == null;
    }

    public static readonly RefBool True = new RefBool();
    public static readonly RefBool False = null;

    private RefBool()
    {
    }
}
```

Now your class can look like this:

```
public class Syncer
{
    private RefBool mIsSyncInProgress = false;

    public void SyncData()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref mIsSyncInProgress, true))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Sync data...
        // It is enough that one thread is syncing data

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref mIsSyncInProgress, false);
    }
}
```

I find this easier to read at the usage site.  I don't find this solution to be perfect, since the `RefBool` class is a bit weird.

You should notice that I used `null` as the false state.  This is to ensure that a variable of type `RefBool` can only ever be `true` or `false`.  If I used two different instances to represent `true` and `false`, then a `RefBool` could also be `null`, which would be an indeterminate state.

The downside to this is that `ToString` won't work right (which is why I didn't bother overriding it).

Comment: It is sad you can't accept two answers. I haven't tested your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`Montior.TryEnter(Object, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679(v=vs.110).aspx), this fits your question/example best.

But this could be written better/more compact with [`Monitor.TryEnter(Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw(v=vs.110).aspx) (*I'll leave that as a suggestion below the first code example*).

```
public class Syncer 
{
    private object lockObject = new object();

    // Data is synced periodically and on user request
    // and these two calls may overlap
    public void SyncData() {
        bool syncInProgress = false;
        try {
           Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, ref syncInProgress); 
           if (syncInProgress) {
               // The critical section.

               // Sync data...
               // It is enough that one thread is syncing data
           }
           else {
               // The lock was not acquired.
               return;
           }
        }
        finally {
           // Ensure that the lock is released.
           if (syncInProgress) {
              Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

*Cleaner* example:

```
public class Syncer 
{
    private object lockObject = new object();

    // Data is synced periodically and on user request
    // and these two calls may overlap
    public void SyncData() {
        if(Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject)){
           try {
               // The critical section.

               // Sync data...
               // It is enough that one thread is syncing data
           }
           finally {
               // Ensure that the lock is released.
               Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
           }
        }
        else {
           // The lock was not acquired.
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `syncInProgress` should be a local variable, not a field, because otherwise: T1 takes lock, sets `syncInProgress` to `true`, T2 tries to take the lock, fails, sets `syncInProgress` to `false` and returns. Now T1 exits, but `syncInProgress` is `false`, so no release.

Comment: @xanatos you are absolutely correct, I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you!